# Firebase reset user password in app without email link in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

How do I reset user password in app without sending email link using firebase in flutter?

Answer (score 0):

If you've already established the user's identity by signing them in, you can [update their password](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/manage-users#set_a_users_password)

Letting a user change the password of an account that they're not signed in to, would be a pretty big security risk though.

If you have another flow for password reset in mind, you can always [update the password](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user) of any account through the Admin SDK, which can be used on trusted environments such as your development machine, a server that you control, or Cloud Functions/Cloud Run.